# Handling fpu exception on windows

Tags: c, windows, exception, fpu

I would like to handle fpu exception on windows, something like:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double b = 0;
    int raised;
    feclearexcept (FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    b /= 0;
    raised = fetestexcept (FE_OVERFLOW | FE_INVALID);
    if (raised & FE_OVERFLOW) { printf("over\n");}
    if (raised & FE_INVALID)  { printf("invalid\n");}

    return 0;
}
```

But on windows. I tried reading the MSDN, but the document is not clear at all. I want to do this with Visual Studio compilers, on both x86 and amd64 archs.

I am not interested in translating the exception in C++ - actually, I am not even interested in the FPU exception, only in knowing the FPU state after some computation, like the example above.

== edit ==

Ok, it looks like it is actually much simpler: using _clearfp is enough:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double b = 0;
    int raised;
    raised = _clearfp();
    b /= 0;
    raised = _clearfp();
    if (raised & SW_INVALID)  { printf("invalid\n");}

    return 0;
}
```

Much better than dealing with exceptions, SEH and other non portable stuff :)

Comment: Works in G++ under Windows, seems to be a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, handling "on windows" is not precise: I meant with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use _statusfp2() to retrieve the floating point status.  Beware that 32-bit uses both FPU and SSE instructions.  Some sample code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  unsigned x86;
  unsigned sse;
  // Test zero-divide
  double d = 0;
  double v = 1 / d;
  _statusfp2(&x86, &sse);
  assert(x86 & _EM_ZERODIVIDE);
  // Test overflow
  v = pow(10, 310.0);
  _statusfp2(&x86, &sse);
  assert(sse & _EM_OVERFLOW);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's Visual Studio, try putting in this line:

```
#pragma   float_control (except, on)
```

More about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb(VS.80).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45ec64h6(VS.80).aspx).

**EDIT:**

If you want to do this in plain C, you'll need to take a look at the [structured exception handling (*SEH*).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: The two links are extremely unclear, unfortunately; I don't understand what float_control is supposed to do: translate the error into C++ exception ? I would like a pure C solution.

Answer (score 0):

These functions are mandated by the standard, so you should have no problem in porting. What exact error are you hitting?

Comment: It does not even compile - AFAIK, MS compilers do not have fenv.h, but have their own mechanism.

Comment: For VS you'd have to rely on the pragma arul mentioned.